# API to check what types of tags is enabled

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, tag

I can't find anything in the documentation of API which would discuss how to check what types of tags is enabled(public or personal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they have declarer it in Unsupported Metadata Types.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Comment: Yes, according to that doc Tag Settings cannot be retrieved or deployed with Metadata API